# Can't find SeiralPort Device by using SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() and got imformation that "DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedByUser"

Tags: uwp, serial-port, windows-server

CustomSerialDeviceAccess is a sample on Microsoft's GitHub and it's for UWP to read/write SerialPort.

The problem is that the sample can open devices on Win10 but get "DeniedByUser" on Windows Server 2019 & Windows Server 2016.
I try to find some different things about Registry and Group Policy but get nothing.
Can you give me some suggestions?
Thx!

Comment: This is a server configuration related issue, you'd better post it to [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=ws2019) Windows Server 2019 forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way to fix the problem.

Use MDM/GP to set the trusted devices policy to ForceAllow.  For GP example, gpedit.msc -> Administrative templates -> Windows components -> AppPrivacy -> Trusted Devices.